Spring PropertySource with dynamic properties
I have the following PropertySource:
DynamicPropertySource extends EnumerablePropertySource<DynamicProperty>

The properties inside the property source are then stored as
Map<String, DynamicProperty>

The property source is loaded with:
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(dynamicPropertySource);

I then inject the property in a class using:
@Value("${my.dynamic.property}")
private DynamicProperty dynamicProperty;

Spring then looks up the property using a method in DynamicPropertySource
@Override
public DynamicProperty getProperty(String name) {...}

When I run this, Spring complains about not having a converter to convert from DynamicProperty to String
I can fix this by adding a converter:
environment.getConversionService()
  .addConverter(DynamicProperty.class, String.class, DynamicProperty::valueAsString);

After this, Spring complains about needing a converter for String to DynamicProperty
I can fix this by adding another converter:
environment.getConversionService()
  .addConverter(String.class, DynamicProperty.class, DynamicProperty::fromString);

But now there are two instances of DynamicProperty. The one that gets injected is not the original instance from the PropertySource. I want to have the same instance because the value contained inside is of a dynamic nature and changes over time. This needs to reflect in the injected property.
Can I stop Spring from converting to a String and back to a DynamicProperty during injection? Or is there a way to find the original DynamicProperty during conversion from String to DynamicProperty?
I want the value which is injected to be the same instance as the one in the source Map of the PropertySource
I do also still want the ability to inject the value as a String where the conversion service will come in
